# Capture desktop/screen and merge sound from laptop mic

Tags: c#, video, screen, capture

I am trying to create desktop application to create video from

1. to capture screen.
2. to record sound from mic.
3. to merge 1 with 2 to create video.
   or
   any easy way to do it in c# or vb.net language.

I used aforg.net which is supporting only video.

I avoid to use third party tools, specially expensive tools.

Comment: i think ffmpeg is not supporting to merge live video and audio. please show the sample of code

Comment: You might need to tell my company then, cos we've been using it for several years to take backups of the webinars and simultaneous translation conference calls in two different audio streams!

Answer (score 1):

I use ffmpeg for this, video via screen-capture-recorder (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop). I control the region that screen-capture-recorder records by writing to the registry before i start ffmpeg. I get audio from virtual audio cable (https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/) (but it's because I record a machine that has no sound card) - you should be able to do it with whatever your mic device is called. You could use something like NAudio to enumerate them, or get ffmpeg to enumerate them and parse its output - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow

I capture two audio streams, using the following ffmpeg args

```
-f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -thread_queue_size 512 -f dshow -i audio="Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable)" -f dshow -i audio="Line 3 (Virtual Audio Cable)" -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -y "{0}"
```

The C# app is responsible for a lot of things, such as taking a screenshot, looking for the thing I want to record, position the region, start ffmpeg etc.. But ff does the heavy lifting.. You don't even need to write any c# for starters, just get FFmpeg working from the command line and recording nicely with various buffer settings etc, then put it to a c# program with Process.Start(command, arguments)